# How do I share session attributes between a servlet and jsp file?

Tags: java, http, jsp, servlets, struts-1

I have a form which when submitted stores data from it's fields to the database. The action forward in the struts-config maps back to the same page on Success/Failure of data insertion into the database. I would like to alert the user once this is successfully completed, so I set a session attribute(i.e. success/failure) in the method of the action class for the form. I then get and print out this session attribute once the jsp page has been accessed again.

So far I have done this in the Action Class:

```
 public static void setJavaScriptNotification(HttpServletRequest request, String notificationText) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("notification_javascript", notificationText);

}
```

And in the jsp file that contains the form I have:

```
    <% String notificationJavaScript = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("notification_javascript");
pageContext.setAttribute("notification_javascript", notificationJavaScript);
request.getSession().removeAttribute("notification_javascript"); %>

<html>
<head>
<logic:present name="notification_javascript">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            function showAlerts() {
                alert("<bean:write name="notification_javascript"/>");
            }
        </script>
    </logic:present>
</head>       
<body onload="doPreOnload(); showAlerts();">
```

When I print out the session attributes in the jsp, I can't find the notification_javascript attribute. I'm new to HTTP, so I could be doing something wrong there.

Comment: Although not related with your question you should avoid scriptlets.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @Alfredo O will switch to jstl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- After setting **notification_javascript** in session in **setJavaScriptNotification()** do the request is forwarded to jsp where **notification_javascript** is accessed.
- If yes, then  **session.getAttribute("notification_javascript")** will do the job.

  **request.setAttribute() vs session.setAttribute()**
- request.setAttribute() will make the key available in following page.
- session.setAttribute() will make the key available in all pages.

Comment: I tried String notificationJavaScript = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("notification_javascript"); in the jsp, but the notification_javascript attribute is not being passed.

Comment: Try session.getAttribute("notification_javascript")

Comment: There was a problem with the javascript in the jsp page I had to resolve. Thanks for the help.